# Problem with ,,Missing \begin{document}

Tags: errors

After updating TexStudio to 3.0.1 I've faced with problem. When I try to compile file, that I have compiled many times earlier, I get error with text: "File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found. \begin{document}". What is wrong?
My code is:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}

.log file content:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)        (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.5.21)  6 SEP 2020 19:42
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-05-15>
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)

! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
     
l.2 \begin{document}
                ^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 223 strings out of 480476
 2655 string characters out of 5903481
 239159 words of memory out of 5000000
 16342 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532636 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 24i,0n,21p,141b,36s stack positions out of    5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: unrelated to texstudio (that is just the editor you are using) but update your tex distribution it looks like you have mis-matched expl3 files

Comment: your document runs without error (but several warnings about obsolete options) if you add `\end{document}`, tested with an up to date texlive 2020.

Comment: Thank You, but after update of TexLive problem still remains. Of course I have \end{document} in its last line. The full error text follows me to line 77 in .sty file, but I haven't any idea what is wrong in its code.

Comment: make the smallest document that you can make that shows the error (probably you just need `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\end{document}` then edit your question to show that example and the full log file that you get

Comment: I did. The error changed, but still remains at all.

Comment: the file changed at a recent release (was l3backend-pdfmode.def, now l3backend-pdftex.def and l3backend-luatex.def) it seems that you have an inconsistent set do tlmgr update --all and possibly fmtutil-sys --all to rebuild the formats

Comment: I've used both commands. It works. Thank You a lot, David!