# Error: l.77 \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}}

Tags: errors, expl3

I freshly installed the texlive-full package through synaptic package manager (Ubuntu), and I seem to have some problem with expl3.

Compiling the following document returns a "Missing \begin{document}" error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\begin{document}
 test 
\end{document}
```

Log as follows.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.1.19)  19 JAN 2021 12:50
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17> (/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count168
\c@section=\count169
\c@subsection=\count170
\c@subsubsection=\count171
\c@paragraph=\count172
\c@subparagraph=\count173
\c@figure=\count174
\c@table=\count175
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/nomencl/nomencl.sty
Package: nomencl 2020/12/29 v5.5 Nomenclature package

(/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/home/fede/texmf/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/home/fede/texmf/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16

(/home/fede/texmf/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count176
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)

(/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-patcholdlatex.sty
Package: scrlfile-patcholdlatex 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (patching 
old LaTeX kernels)

(/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty
Package: scrlogo 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (logo)
))
(/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (loader) 


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.77      \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}}
                                         %
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.77      \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}}
                                         %
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 758 strings out of 480906
 11450 string characters out of 5910772
 253744 words of memory out of 5000000
 16402 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 535088 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 63i,0n,54p,234b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

In the example above I used the package nomenclature, but it seems to me that the problem should be somewhere else: I get a bunch of errors if I try to use \NewDocumentCommand or load the package xparse.

This seems to be related with this other [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561509/problem-with-missing-begindocument), but that solution (in the comments) did not appear to work for me.

Any idea on what's going on?

Comment: your format and the expl3 code is out of sync. One typical source of the problem is that you have a local format shadowing the system formats. Run `kpsewhich --engine=pdftex --all pdflatex.fmt` to check if you have more than one.

Comment: That is weird, from a newly-installed `texlive-full`.  I'd recommend you install vanilla TeX Live (from here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html):  It's a _lot_ easier and better to manage than the packaged version for Ubuntu

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - there seems to be only one: the output is /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik -  I had actually tried to install vanilla latex first (following the instructions here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu - 2nd answer), but I seemed to encounter the same issue. I assumed I screwed up something, so I uninstalled it (using the instructions provided on the same page) hoping that the packaged version of tex-live would work out of the box.

Comment: Ah.  You have a local texmf tree in `/home/fede/texmf`, and the version of `expl3.sty` there dates from 2021-01-09, while the version preloaded on LaTeX is 2020-07-17, thus the error.  Try (re)moving `l3kernel`, `l3packages`, and `l3backend` from `/home/fede/texmf/tex/latex` and run your document again

Comment: It fixed it, thanks a lot! This makes me wonder, is it good to have anything at all in ~/texmf? Would it be safer to remove that folder altogether? 

(if you post your comment as an answer I will be happy to accept it)