# Problem updating Tex distribution causing leading to l3backend issued

Tags: errors, mac, l3build

I'm running into an issue compiling documents where it cannot find `l3backend-pdfmode.def`. I've found a fair number of related questions ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561509/problem-with-missing-begindocument), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499082/file-l3backend-pdfmode-def-not-found-when-loading-expl3), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577579/l3backend-issue-after-kernel-update)) and they all point to needing to upgrade a few things. I've run `sudo tlmgr update --all --self` and `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` and am still running into the same problem. The problem seems to be that even after running them I still have an old version of the L3 Programming layer and cannot seem to figure out how to update it:

```
% pdflatex \\stop                                                      
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

I do not see any obvious errors when running `fmtutil-sys` but the output is long so maybe I'm missing something. The end is:

```
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/luatex/optex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/luatex/optex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: disabled formats: 5
fmtutil [INFO]: successfully rebuilt formats: 54
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 59
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
```

I'm on a mac running Big Sur.

Comment: check if you have more than one format with `kpsewhich --all --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt`.

Comment: Turns out I do, I am not sure which one to delete. There is one in `/usr/local/texlive` and one in `/Users/[username]/library`

Comment: delete the one that is not updated by fmtutil-sys (so probably username).

Comment: And it works now after rerunning `mktexlsr` thank you so much for the help.